# What is the name of this game where you place colored cubes on a tiled grid?

Tags: identify-this-game

I played a game about 5 years ago; pretty sure it would be classified as a Euro game. You have a player mat made by putting a few tiles together, I think a 2x2 square of square tiles. Each tile has a grid on it, I think it's a 6x6 grid or so.

On your turn, you take small cubes and place them on your board; 1 cube per grid space. You can place up to 2 cubes on a turn as long as the 2 cubes are adjacent to each other. There might be 2 or 3 different color cubes you can choose to place, I can't remember for sure. The object is to end up with the most coverage or to cover specific areas, something like that.

Ring any bells?

Comment: It sounds similar to Blockus (i.e. square grid that players take turns placing pieces on), but the blockus pieces are tetris-esque, not single squares

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tracked it down... Mykerinos.

http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/21441/mykerinos

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if you're not hoping for some sort of better answer.